# Text matching order by relevance

Tags: mysql, database, sorting, textmatching

In MySQL is there a way we can order the results in order of set of rules also used for filtering the results?

**E.g.** if we have a name field and input from the user then I would like to filter and sort the records as following

If we match the input against the name field

1. Exact Match
2. 1st keyword of input exact match for name
3. 2nd keyword of input exact match for name
4. Name starts with 1st keyword
5. Name starts with 2nd keyword

I would like to filter the results based on the above mentioned cases and order them in above listed sequence.

Input : **two three**

Data :
| one           |
| two           |
| three         |
| one two three |
| one three two |
| three one two |
| two three one |

Output :
| two           |
| three         |
| two three one |
| three one two |

Full Text Search might a possible solution but from my past experience it does not always give an expected relevancy value to exactly order in the above mentioned manner.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected output.

Comment: Have you tried 5 separate queries UNIONed together?

Comment: Isn't 'two three' a better match than 'two' or 'three'?